# Were there any mythological beings which could duplicate themselves?

Tags: mythical-creatures

A recurring superpower in comics and such is the ability to duplicate or clone oneself, seen in characters such as Multiplex, Amoeba, Multiple Man, etc.

Were there any figures or creatures from mythology that had similar abilities?

Comment: According to https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SelfDuplication, "Pan, from Greek mythology, had the ability to split into multiple "Panes", each with its own name. Three of them, Agreos, Nominos and Aegipan, are described as having their own unique appearances, personalities and abilities."  I've had trouble finding additional reference for this ability, but this is the only answer I've been able to find.